# How to retrieve database relationships without EF

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlfu

I have a very basic question about database programming, here's the problem:

I want to create/read/edit/etc.. data from database without using Entity Framework, and for this job I've chosen SqlFu.

I want to put the stored procedures to create, update, delete on the database and the views to get entities.

My doubt is: If I have an table *Employee*, that has a one-to-many relationship to *Tasks* table, when I create a Sql View to retrieve *Employee* entity, should I retrieve the data in *Tasks* table that is related to the employee?

If so, how to do that with a single View in SQL Server? If not, I should have different Sql Views that retrieve data from each table and *bind* the relationship in the application?

I'm a bit lost in this subject :S

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need. You can retrieve any data from any table/view without need to always retrieve data from any related table's.

On ORM layer it's should be implemented as lazy loading - like in EF. But not in MicroORM's like SQLFu - there you should manually do something like

```
employeeObject.Tasks = db.Query<Task>("select * from tasks where employeid=@0", employeeObject.Id)
```

When and if you actually need it.

Yes, you should retrieve data from each table and bind the relationship inside application code.